# Warning: comparison between pointer and integer. If statement

Tags: c, scanf

I can't understand why this simple code, that is storing an answer from the user is giving me back this error.

- I would like to save the answer into a variable `q_ai` and be able to use this variable in an if.

this below is my code:

```
//INPUT TRY 0
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//setting game:
char q_ai;      //want to play against ai? question about ai.


int main(void)
{   

    printf("Do you want to play vs AI? \n   Y/N? \n ");
    scanf("%c",q_ai);       
    printf("q_ai == %c\n",q_ai);
    printf("sizeof(q_ai): %d",sizeof(q_ai));
    
    if(q_ai=="y") {
        printf("you will play against AI");
    }
    
    if(q_ai=="n") {
        printf("you will play 1v1");
    }
    
    
}
```

How can I solve this problem? thanks

Comment: `q_ay` is a `char` which is **the integer** in question; `"y"` is a string which is **the pointer** in question. To compare strings use `if (strcmp("foo", "bar") == 0)`, to compare chars use `if ('a' == 'b')`

Comment: try using single quotes `'` instead of double `"`

Comment: you need to pass a pointer to scanf, e.g. `scanf("%c", &q_ai);` and  the if's should use `'` (e.g. `if(q_ai=='y')`) since you're just comparing a single character.

Comment: Also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c

Comment: BTW this warning should almost always be treated as an error.

Comment: Rolled back to what the comments are mentioning. Please don't make 'progress' updates to the posted code.

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado thanks I didn't know that double quotes would mean char array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have right now is comparing a character to pointers to strings (`"y"` and `"n"`).  You need to compare the character `q_ai` to characters (`'y'` and `'n'`).

```
if(q_ai=='y') {
    printf("you will play against AI");
}

if(q_ai=='n') {
    printf("you will play 1v1");
}
```